# Unable to load SpanBert model with transformers package

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have some questions regarding of SpanBert loading using transformers packages.

I downloaded the pre-trained file from [SpanBert](https://github.com/facebookresearch/SpanBERT) GitHub Repo and `vocab.txt` from Bert. Here is the code I used for loading:

```py
model = BertModel.from_pretrained(config_file=config_file,
                                  pretrained_model_name_or_path=model_file,
                                  vocab_file=vocab_file)
model.to("cuda")
```

where

- `config_file` -> `config.json`
- `model_file` -> `pytorch_model.bin`
- `vocab_file` -> `vocab.txt`

But I got the `UnicodeDecoderError` with the above code saying that `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`

I also tried loading SpanBert with the method mentioned [here](https://huggingface.co/SpanBERT/spanbert-large-cased). But it returned `OSError: file SpanBERT/spanbert-base-cased not found`.

Do you have any suggestions on loading the pre-trained model correctly? Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of transformers do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download the pre-trained weights from the Github page.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/SpanBERT

[SpanBERT (base & cased): 12-layer, 768-hidden, 12-heads , 110M parameters](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fairseq/models/spanbert_hf_base.tar.gz)

[SpanBERT (large & cased): 24-layer, 1024-hidden, 16-heads, 340M parameters](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fairseq/models/spanbert_hf_base.tar.gz)

2. Extract them to a folder, for example I extracted to spanbert_hf_base folder which contains a `.bin` file and a `config.json` file.
3. You can use **AutoModel** to load the model and simple bert tokenizer. From their repo:

> These models have the same format as the HuggingFace BERT models, so you can easily replace them with our SpanBET models.

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModel
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('spanbert_hf_base/') # the path to .bin and config.json

from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

b = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode('hi this is me, mr. meeseeks', add_special_tokens=True, max_length = 512)).unsqueeze(0)

out = model(b)
```

Out:

```
(tensor([[[-0.1204, -0.0806, -0.0168,  ..., -0.0599, -0.1932, -0.0967],
          [-0.0851, -0.0980,  0.0039,  ..., -0.0563, -0.1655, -0.0156],
          [-0.1111, -0.0318,  0.0141,  ..., -0.0518, -0.1068, -0.1271],
          [-0.0317, -0.0441, -0.0306,  ..., -0.1049, -0.1940, -0.1919],
          [-0.1200,  0.0277, -0.0372,  ..., -0.0930, -0.0627,  0.0143],
          [-0.1204, -0.0806, -0.0168,  ..., -0.0599, -0.1932, -0.0967]]],
        grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward>),
 tensor([[-9.7530e-02,  1.6328e-01,  9.3202e-03,  1.1010e-01,  7.3047e-02,
          -1.7635e-01,  1.0046e-01, -1.4826e-02,  9.2583e-
         ............
```

Comment: Thanks! In that case do I need to download the ```vocab.txt``` and put it into the folder?

Comment: Nope as BertTokenizer works on SpanBert, you don't need that. However, if you want to use the AutoTokenizer you have to have the vocab.txt

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi how do you feed the `out` to the loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss() though? It looks like dimensions are not compatible following the code in SpanBERT: `tmp_eval_loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, num_labels), label_ids.view(-1))` where `logits` is same as `out` in your code

Comment: Don't you need to use the tokenizer they used to train with? 
Also, is it possible to train a new SpanBERT model using transformers?